# CSS: Floating DIVs in an odd order?

Tags: css, layout, html, css-float

Ok, so I am trying to write some CSS for an Amazon WebStore. They format the pages like this:

[image: Default Layout]

With some tweaking, and the removal of the right column (unneeded for our layout) I have managed to get the layout like shown below:

[image: What I have now.]

The problem is, the red areas are just empty, and I would like to make the left column take up the entire side, like so:

[image: What I would like.]

Here is where the problem comes in. I know a little about floats, but I also know it depends on how they are placed, in what order. They put them in the order like this:

```
<header divs>
<top divs>
<left divs>
<center divs>
<right divs>
<bottom divs>
<footer divs>
```

Everything in between the Header and Footer (top, left, right, center, and bottom) are contained in a wrapper div.

What would be a general float setup for this? I cannot rearrange the DIV order, so I just need to know if this can be done or not, and if so, some code would be great.

Unfortunately, I cannot post any HTML or anything because you cannot access it. I just need a basic representation, like these divs have this float, this has this, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping top, center and bottom in a wrapper and floating that?

Comment: HTML is uneditable, otherwise I would have done that. Only CSS can be edited.

Comment: You could probably hide `top`, `left` and `bottom` and then just create your own within `center`.

Comment: I see. How about the widths of the elements. Are they fixed or relative?

Comment: You know what though, maybe this would work? Place a margin on the wrapper DIV to push them all over, and then position the left column absolutely? That would pull it out of the wrapper and let me place it on the side where the margin pushed the Top, Center, and Bottom DIVs over. Possible?

Comment: Relative widths. And the layout is done with a drag and drop system of 'widgets' so I cannot hide all those DIVs because there is info that must be there that cannot be moved.

Answer (score 1):

Only tested in Chrome, so you'll want to look at this in other browsers.

Alternatively, you could maybe make use of `display: table-cell` to accomplish what you want, but not without breaking support for that certain browser that many people hate.

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6SjEm/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="top">TOP</div>
<div id="left">LEFT</div>
<div id="center">CENTER</div>
<div id="right">RIGHT</div>
<div id="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { font: 20px sans-serif; color: #FFF; text-align: center; }
#header, #footer { background: #000; height: 100px; }
#top, #bottom { background: #333; height: 50px; }
#right { display: none; }

#top { margin-left: 220px; }
#left {
    background: #666;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 220px;
}
#center { 
    background: #999;
    clear: right;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 220px;
}
#bottom { margin-left: 220px; }
#footer { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that requires a fixed size for the top div, which will be a different size on every page.

Comment: What about page width?  Fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use the negative margins trick for top, center, and bottom, depending on the structure of the markup.  See http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/.